# How to filter many to many structure in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I got a many to many user and role structure

**users**
id
name

**roles**
id
name

**role_user**
user_id
role_id

**Model**

**User.php**

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}
```

**Role.php**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

There are two data `admins` and `members` in roles table, I would like to know to to filter users which role is admins.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should give you all users who are admins.

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', '=', 'admins');
})->get();
```

You can see more information on the `has()` method at http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations