# laravel retrieve all users where value match pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So im trying to make relationship between `user` `roles` and `profiles` everything works connected on creation but i don't know how to filter out when i want to list users by specific role or profile.

Here is a table structure that i have now. Each table corresponds to it's model, so table `users` have model `User` table `roles` have model `Role` and there is a pivot table `role_user` that connects users with roles.

This would be role table

```
+----+----------+---------------+
| id |   name   |  Description  |
+----+----------+---------------+
|  1 | admin    | Administrator |
|  2 | client   | Client        |
|  3 | operator | Operator      |
+----+----------+---------------+
```

This would be pivot table for user role

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | role_id |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |       1 |       3 |
|  2 |       2 |       1 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

And this would be user table normally

```
+----+--------+-----------------+
| id |  name  |      Email      |
+----+--------+-----------------+
|  1 | Mario  | mario@email.tld |
|  2 | Luighi | lui@email.tld   |
+----+--------+-----------------+
```

So if i would list all account that is very simple, as i would just use

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

  $users = User::get();

  return view('users/index', compact('users'));
}
```

If i want to filter users by specific name or email i would just filter

```
$users = User::where('name', 'Mario')->get();
```

That would retrieve all users where matching name is mario.

Now something more complex is where i stumbled upon and i couldn't quite find answers on internet.

I want to retrieve all users where user role from pivot table matches role from role table.

Example would be

```
Retrieve All Users WHERE (pivot table) role_user EQUALS name OPERATOR from role table
```

That would return user Mario, as his user id is 1 and in pivot table that user_id matches role_id 3 which in roles table is role named OPERATOR.

Comment: Check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378889/how-to-filter-many-to-many-structure-in-laravel?rq=1)

Comment: Look at the with functionality in laravel.

Comment: That's it that's what is the answer mustafa96m, it's not appearing on search results nowhere, and all videos i watched, never mentioned, but on laravel documentations is just under newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach by joining user table to pivot table and filter on where role_id = operator_id

```
$operator_id =    
DB::table('roles')->where('name','=','operator')->first()->id;

DB::table('users') ->join('pivot', function ($join)       
   { $join->on('users.id', '=', 'pivot.user_id') ->where('pivot.role_id', 
   '=', $operator_id); }) ->get();
```